# Reading dynamic value for *jhiHasAnyAuthority

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-directive

I am new to Angular and jhipster stack, we are building an angular - spring-boot project with jhipster stack. For rendering the menu items in the Nav Bar we are using '***jhiHasAnyAuthority**' in the navbar.component.html like below:

```
<li *jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN' ngbDropdown routerLinkActive="active">
```

Is there any way we can read the value for **jhiHasAnyAuthority** dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "dynamically" but you can inject `AccountService` into the constructor of your component and use its functions and in particular `hasAnyAuthority()`. This is what the directive uses. Look at its definition in `src/main/webapp/app/core/auth/account.service.ts` of your project.

There are many examples on how it is used in your generated project.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a reference to the instance of the directive via ViewChild

```js
@ViewChild(HasAnyAuthorityDirective)
set authorityDirective(val: HasAnyAuthorityDirective) {
    this._authorityDirective = val;
};
```

You'll be able to check the values it contains then